# Python script on Unix writes on csv file but unreadable symbols at the end of the file in Windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, csv, character-encoding

I am still learning python and I wrote script that is logging to cisco devices and run command and write to csv file and send as email attachment but when open  the file on my Windows machine it has unreadable symbols:
[image]

If router is not reachable just writes file saying device down and it shows 0 as empty file in Unix but on Windows i see this:
[image]

Below is the script:

```
> def ssh_conn():
>     user = 'xxxxxxx'
>     passwd = 'xxxxxx'
>     file2 = ("hostfile")
>     hosts = open(file2,'r')
>     for host in hosts:
>             try:
>                    hostIp = host.split(',')[1]
>                    device = host.split(',')[0]
>                    session = paramiko.SSHClient()
>                    session.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>                    session.connect(hostIp.strip(), username = user, password = passwd)
>                    connection = session.invoke_shell()
>                    connection.send("terminal  width 0\n")
>                    connection.send("sh archive config differences nvram:startup-config system:running-config | exc !|Diff\n")
>                    time.sleep(1)
>                    output = connection.recv(5000)
>                    f = open(device +".csv", "w")
>                    f.write(output+'\n')
>                    f.close()
>             except:
>                    #f1 =codecs.open(device +"-DOWN.csv", "w", encoding="utf_16")
>                    f1 = open(device +"-DOWN.csv", "w")
>                    f1.close()
>                    pass
>     files = glob.glob('*.csv')
>     for file in files:
>         if os.stat(file).st_size > 0:
>             try:
>                df=pd.read_csv(file,skiprows = 1).dropna()
>                if len(df) <=2:
>                   os.remove(file)
>                elif len(df) > 2:
>                   df=pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = 1, header=True).dropna()
>                   df.to_csv(file, index=False)
>                else:
>                   print 'Empty File..passing'
>                pass
>             except ValueError:
>                 print 'Modified file'
>             pass ssh_conn()  print "Completed!"
```

I have tried using some encoders but same. Also was trying to write to txt file is the same. Hope you can provide a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issues was with the script sending the email attachments which I fixed so closing the question .The script above is working fine